# no se me activa timepicker (materialize)

Tags: php, javascript, html5, pdo, timepicker

tengo un problema no se me activa el timepicker para poder seleccionar las hora de entrada y salida

**input**

```
  <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
  <input type="text" id="hora_entrada" class="timepicker" 
   name="hora_entrada"/>
   <label for="cuentas" class="black-text ">Hora de Entrada:</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
 <input type="text" id="hora_salida" class="timepicker" name="hora_salida"/>
 <label for="cuentas" class="black-text ">Hora de Salida:</label>
 </div>




  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!--  Scripts-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('select').material_select();
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
    $('.timepicker').pickatime({
          default: 'now', // Set default time: 'now', '1:30AM', '16:30'
          fromnow: 0,       // set default time to * milliseconds from now (using with default = 'now')
         twelvehour: false, // Use AM/PM or 24-hour format
         donetext: 'OK', // text for done-button
         cleartext: 'Clear', // text for clear-button
         canceltext: 'Cancel', // Text for cancel-button,
         container: undefined, // ex. 'body' will append picker to body
         autoclose: false, // automatic close timepicker
         ampmclickable: true, // make AM PM clickable
         aftershow: function(){} //Function for after opening timepicker
                 });

                 });
           </script>
```

**error que emite por consola**

```
 webExtensionWallet is defined:for nebulas
 jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).material_select is not a 
 function TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
  (http://localhost:8080/SAHV1/admin/alquilar.php?id_habitacion=4:259:17)
  at j (http://localhost:8080/SAHV1/js/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
  at k (http://localhost:8080/SAHV1/js/jquery.min.js:2:30313) undefined
  r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
   jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function
   at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (alquilar.php?id_habitacion=4:259)
   at j (jquery.min.js:2)
   at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: porque usas 2 versiones de Jquery en tu carga?

Comment: pero igual ponga cualquiera de las dos no se me activa no se que pasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listo problema resuelto

anexo solución

```
       <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
           <script src="../0.100.2js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```